# installation of mysql gem failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql-connector

everything is set so far and the only issue with mysql2 I saw many solutions but none of them are working for me. it asks me to check some mkmf.log which I don't understand.
I even tried solutions from similar questions but nothing worked

> rails version 6.1.4 and ruby 3.0.2 on windows 10 pro

below are the two files it tells me to refer to for resolving the issue

**mkmf.log**

```
have_func: checking for rb_absint_size()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong  -m64   -lx64-msvcrt-ruby300  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return !!argv[argc];
8: }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong  -m64   -lx64-msvcrt-ruby300  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
12:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
13:   }
14: 
15:   return !!argv[argc];
16: }
17: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_absint_size; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong  -m64   -lx64-msvcrt-ruby300  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
12:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
13:   }
14: 
15:   return !!argv[argc];
16: }
17: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_absint_singlebit_p; return !p; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... -------------------- yes

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong  -m64   -lx64-msvcrt-ruby300  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:17:57: error: 'rb_wait_for_single_fd' undeclared (first use in this function)
   17 | int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_wait_for_single_fd; return !p; }
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
conftest.c:17:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
12:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
13:   }
14: 
15:   return !!argv[argc];
16: }
17: int t(void) { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))rb_wait_for_single_fd; return !p; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby30-x64/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -O3 -fno-fast-math -fstack-protector-strong conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby30-x64/lib -L. -pipe -s -fstack-protector-strong  -m64   -lx64-msvcrt-ruby300  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
 1: #include "ruby.h"
 2: 
 3: #include <winsock2.h>
 4: #include <windows.h>
 5: 
 6: /*top*/
 7: extern int t(void);
 8: int main(int argc, char **argv)
 9: {
10:   if (argc > 1000000) {
11:     int (* volatile tp)(void)=(int (*)(void))&t;
12:     printf("%d", (*tp)());
13:   }
14: 
15:   return !!argv[argc];
16: }
17: extern void rb_wait_for_single_fd();
18: int t(void) { rb_wait_for_single_fd(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

**gem_make**

```
current directory: C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20210724-5736-2jo1ju.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysqlclient-dir
    --without-mysqlclient-dir
    --with-mysqlclient-include
    --without-mysqlclient-include=${mysqlclient-dir}/include
    --with-mysqlclient-lib
    --without-mysqlclient-lib=${mysqlclient-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `block in find_library': undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `collect'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `find_library'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/3.0.0/mysql2-0.5.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```